# Запрос: найти строку таблицы tab1, значение поля "pole1" которой, не встречается в поле "pole2" таблицы tab2

Tags: mysql, pdo, modx

Возникла необходимость написать запрос вида:
найти строку таблицы tab1, значение поля "pole1" которой, не встречается в поле "pole2" таблицы tab2.

Всё действо будет выполнятся в modx. Но мне бы только смысл понять, поэтому ответ принимается и в sql. А дальше я переконвертирую) Заранее благодарен.

Comment: LEFT JOIN .. WHERE .. IS NULL

Comment: Спасибо большое) Точно по Вашему сделал)